# Alternative CSS styling doesn't appear for visitors - SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, branding, style-library

My SharePoint 2013 site is branded and uses a custom masterpage and an alternative CSS which is stored in the style library of the site and called from the master page and also specified as the file to be used by the site as a channel.

Now, the members of the site and owner of the site can see the Site appropriately with branding and CSS styling.

But the visitors can see the master page, but the CSS is not applied to it.

The three groups have different permission levels, but the branding and CSS should be seen by every group irrespective of the permission level, but it seems like visitors with "read" permission level cannot see the CSS styling.

Is there anything specific that I am missing that needs to be done here, is this a bug or simply............

HOW DO I FIX THIS.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can vistor user access style library? you can check by directly browsing the url from vistor loging.

Answer (score 0):

Is the alternative css file in the libary checked in? Was my Problem last time too

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-out-check-in-or-discard-changes-to-files-in-a-library-7e2c12a9-a874-4393-9511-1378a700f6de?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: I doubt @dev.Manderson that the problem is with checkin, as member group are able to see the changes.

Comment: i dont know if this was the problem, but its one of those cases where you dont know how but its fixed. So its fixed now and I dont know how, the file was checked out, i checked it in and its checked out again now, but the issue resolved. @Ravindra